# HTML Element returned Null from external JS module

Tags: javascript, html, module

Read many questions regarding this here. Searched across MDN Docs & W3Schools etc. But I have not been able to fix this issue and this is overwhelming me. It seems like very normal and easy thing but isn't working out for me. Probably I have some issues here. The thing is I have 3 different files:
1.`index.html` contains only a button and script tag.
2.`qn1.js` contains some functions. It is a module & imports an object from the third file. 
3.`personAccounts.js` contains an export object.

**The error:**

When I loaded the file in the browser, the index file is as
`<script src="day8/level3/qn1.js" type="module"></script>`
`<button id="btn" > Click here! </button>`

and the module contains:
`document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", comm());`

 So, the `comm()` function is executed automatically for the first time and is never executed when click on the `button`

As per  [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344995/html-element-not-detected-in-external-js-file)  I tried to make sure that HTML is loaded before Script is executed:

```
 window.load = function(){
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", comm());
 }
```

But here, the function isn't executed even a single time. I even tried [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)
but nothing seems to work.
Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: First thing I'm noticing is that you are calling `comm()` immediately as you are adding the event listener, rather than when the event is fired. I think you may want `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", comm);`, passing the function reference, rather than calling it.

Comment: Also, it's `window.onload`, not `window.load`.

Comment: thanks guys!! referencing the function and changing the event to `onload` really did solved the problem. :) @mykaf and @Unmitigated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for helping with the errors that I was making in this context: 
 First thing I'm noticing is that you are calling `comm()` immediately as you are adding the event listener, rather than when the event is fired. I think you may want `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", comm);`, passing the function reference, rather than calling it. [By Mykaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599011/mykaf)


Also, it's `window.onload`, not `window.load`
[By Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated)

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", comm);
 }
```